# IntelliJ Idea command line code inspection fails

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, continuous-integration

I am trying to set up command line code inspection with IntelliJ Idea, but the program seems to crash. The project builds with Gradle.

I get the following errors (full stack trace below)

```
2022-11-11 09:17:13,214 [  15890] SEVERE - #o.j.p.g.GradleCommandLineProjectConfigurator - Gradle resolve failure <unnamed>:0
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: The project directory does not exist!
```

It is not clear which directory it is trying to access, and I have not been able to reproduce this error by calling Gradle directly. This error also appears when I run Idea graphically, and it seems to work just fine so it might be a red herring. But in that case I have no idea what's wrong.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be very welcome!

`build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'java-library'
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url '/opt/java-deps'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.8'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0'
    implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src', 'generated']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['src']
        }
    }
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(11)
    }
}

gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Werror" << "-Xlint:all"
    }

    tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
        options {
            showAll()

            // https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2354
            addStringOption("Xwerror", "-quiet")
        }
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

application {
    mainClass = 'tests.Main'
}
```

`settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.name = 'vt'
```

Stack trace (some of the stack traces are trimmed due to post size limits):

```
vkl@debian:~/*$ idea inspect . .idea/inspections/Project_Default.xml inspection
2022-11-11 09:16:59,517 [   2193]   WARN - #c.i.n.i.NotificationGroupManagerImpl - Notification group CodeWithMe is already registered (group=com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup@52ca8e3). Plugin descriptor: PluginDescriptor(name=Code With Me, id=com.jetbrains.codeWithMe, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=/opt/intellij_idea/plugins/cwm-plugin, version=221.5591.52, package=null, isBundled=true)
Info  | RdCoroutineScope          | 10:JobScheduler FJ pool 0/4 | RdCoroutineHost overridden
2022-11-11 09:17:09,115 [  11791] SEVERE - #c.i.o.a.i.FlushQueue - null
java.awt.HeadlessException
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTree.checkDragEnabled(JTree.java:1222)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTree.setDragEnabled(JTree.java:1216)
        at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ui.ChangesListView.<init>(ChangesListView.java:59)
        at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ChangesViewPanel$MyChangesListView.<init>(ChangesViewPanel.kt:89)
        at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ChangesViewPanel.<init>(ChangesViewPanel.kt:30)
        at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ChangesViewManager$ChangesViewToolWindowPanel.<init>(ChangesViewManager.java:353)
        at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ChangesViewManager.initToolWindowPanel(ChangesViewManager.java:179)
        at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ChangesViewManager.updateCommitWorkflow(ChangesViewManager.java:272)
        at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ChangesViewManager.lambda$new$0(ChangesViewManager.java:117)
        at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.invokeMethod(MessageBusImpl.java:639)
        at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.invokeListener(MessageBusImpl.java:621)
        at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.access$300(MessageBusImpl.java:34)
        at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl$MessagePublisher.executeOrAddToQueue(MessageBusImpl.java:209)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.BaseExpirableExecutorMixinImpl.access$scheduleWithinConstraints$s1153900543(BaseExpirableExecutorMixinImpl.kt:12)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.BaseExpirableExecutorMixinImpl$scheduleWithinConstraints$$inlined$Runnable$1.run(Runnable.kt:19)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:215)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$100(TransactionGuardImpl.java:22)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$1.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:197)
        at  
...
java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)
2022-11-11 09:17:09,137 [  11813] SEVERE - #c.i.o.a.i.FlushQueue - IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1  Build #IC-221.5591.52
2022-11-11 09:17:09,139 [  11815] SEVERE - #c.i.o.a.i.FlushQueue - JDK: 11.0.14.1; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2022-11-11 09:17:09,141 [  11817] SEVERE - #c.i.o.a.i.FlushQueue - OS: Linux
2022-11-11 09:17:09,671 [  12347]   WARN - #g.r.GitUntrackedFilesHolder - Ignoring ignored file under another root: *; root: /src; mapped root: null
2022-11-11 09:17:09,675 [  12351]   WARN - #g.r.GitUntrackedFilesHolder - Ignoring ignored file under another root: *; root: /src; mapped root: null
2022-11-11 09:17:09,676 [  12352]   WARN - #g.r.GitUntrackedFilesHolder - Ignoring ignored file under another root: *; root: /src; mapped root: null
2022-11-11 09:17:09,677 [  12353]   WARN - #g.r.GitUntrackedFilesHolder - Ignoring ignored file under another root: *; root: /src; mapped root: null
2022-11-11 09:17:09,679 [  12355]   WARN - #g.r.GitUntrackedFilesHolder - Ignoring ignored file under another root: *; root: /src; mapped root: null
2022-11-11 09:17:09,680 [  12356]   WARN - #g.r.GitUntrackedFilesHolder - Ignoring ignored file under another root: *; root: /src; mapped root: null
2022-11-11 09:17:09,682 [  12358]   WARN - #g.r.GitUntrackedFilesHolder - Ignoring ignored file under another root: *; root: /src; mapped root: null
2022-11-11 09:17:09,685 [  12361]   WARN - #g.r.GitUntrackedFilesHolder - Ignoring ignored file under another root: *; root: /src; mapped root: null
2022-11-11 09:17:09,700 [  12376]   WARN - #g.r.GitUntrackedFilesHolder - Ignoring ignored file under another root: *; root: /src; mapped root: null
2022-11-11 09:17:09,719 [  12395]   WARN - #g.r.GitUntrackedFilesHolder - Ignoring ignored files under another root: 48 files total
2022-11-11 09:17:12,825 [  15501]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.g.p.s.i.SyncIssueUsageReporterImpl - Multiple sync failures reported. Discarding: SDK_BUILD_TOOLS_TOO_LOW
2022-11-11 09:17:13,214 [  15890] SEVERE - #o.j.p.g.GradleCommandLineProjectConfigurator - Gradle resolve failure <unnamed>:0
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: The project directory does not exist!
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(GradleExecutionErrorHandler.java:197)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.java:46)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.doGetUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:167)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:48)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.checkErrorsWithoutQuickFixes(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:62)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$1.getUserFriendlyError(GradleProjectResolver.java:877)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:806)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:775)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.lambda$execute$0(GradleExecutionHelper.java:138)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.maybeFixSystemProperties(GradleExecutionHelper.java:165)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.lambda$execute$1(GradleExecutionHelper.java:138)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.GradleConnectorService$Companion.withGradleConnection(GradleConnectorService.kt:181)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.GradleConnectorService.withGradleConnection(GradleConnectorService.kt)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:130)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:154)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:74)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:43)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:36)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:48)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:115)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:151)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:135)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.executeImpl(ExternalSystemUtil.java:491)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.lambda$execute$0(ExternalSystemUtil.java:327)
        at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceHeavyActivities.suspendIndexingAndRun(DumbServiceHeavyActivities.java:21)
        at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.suspendIndexingAndRun(DumbServiceImpl.java:190)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:327)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:614)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.startTask(CoreProgressManager.java:442)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.startTask(ProgressManagerImpl.java:114)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressInCurrentThread$10(CoreProgressManager.java:561)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:189)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$12(CoreProgressManager.java:608)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:683)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:639)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:607)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:60)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcessWithProgressInCurrentThread(CoreProgressManager.java:561)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.run(CoreProgressManager.java:381)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.Task.queue(Task.java:119)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil.refreshProject(ExternalSystemUtil.java:616)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil.refreshProject(ExternalSystemUtil.java:282)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.autoimport.ProjectAware.reloadProject(ProjectAware.kt:62)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.autoimport.AutoImportProjectTracker.reloadProject(AutoImportProjectTracker.kt:141)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.autoimport.AutoImportProjectTracker.access$reloadProject(AutoImportProjectTracker.kt:33)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.autoimport.AutoImportProjectTracker$scheduleProjectRefresh$1.invoke(AutoImportProjectTracker.kt:76)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.autoimport.AutoImportProjectTracker$scheduleProjectRefresh$1.invoke(AutoImportProjectTracker.kt:33)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.autoimport.AutoImportProjectTracker$schedule$1.invoke(AutoImportProjectTracker.kt:103)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.autoimport.AutoImportProjectTracker$schedule$1.invoke(AutoImportProjectTracker.kt:33)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.autoimport.update.PriorityEatUpdate$Companion$invoke$1.run(PriorityEatUpdate.kt:15)
        at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.queue(MergingUpdateQueue.java:347)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.autoimport.AutoImportProjectTracker.schedule(AutoImportProjectTracker.kt:98)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.autoimport.AutoImportProjectTracker.scheduleProjectRefresh(AutoImportProjectTracker.kt:76)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.GradleCommandLineProjectConfigurator.importProjects(GradleCommandLineProjectConfigurator.kt:95)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.GradleCommandLineProjectConfigurator.configureProject(GradleCommandLineProjectConfigurator.kt:75)
        at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionApplicationBase.configureProject(InspectionApplicationBase.java:462)
        at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionApplicationBase.lambda$runUnderProgress$22(InspectionApplicationBase.java:698)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:189)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$12(CoreProgressManager.java:608)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:683)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:639)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:607)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:60)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
        at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionApplicationBase.runUnderProgress(InspectionApplicationBase.java:697)
        at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionApplicationBase.runAnalysis(InspectionApplicationBase.java:492)
        at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionApplicationBase.runAnalysisOnScope(InspectionApplicationBase.java:449)
        at ...
2022-11-11 09:17:13,227 [  15903] SEVERE - #o.j.p.g.GradleCommandLineProjectConfigurator - IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1  Build #IC-221.5591.52
2022-11-11 09:17:13,228 [  15904] SEVERE - #o.j.p.g.GradleCommandLineProjectConfigurator - JDK: 11.0.14.1; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2022-11-11 09:17:13,229 [  15905] SEVERE - #o.j.p.g.GradleCommandLineProjectConfigurator - OS: Linux
2022-11-11 09:17:13,266 [  15942]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.g.p.s.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed in 2 s 236 ms. The project directory does not exist!
2022-11-11 09:17:15,351 [  18027] SEVERE - #c.i.c.InspectionApplicationBase - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Gradle project <unnamed>:0 resolve failed.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Gradle project <unnamed>:0 resolve failed.
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.GradleCommandLineProjectConfigurator$StateNotificationListener.waitForImportEnd(GradleCommandLineProjectConfigurator.kt:196)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.GradleCommandLineProjectConfigurator.configureProject(GradleCommandLineProjectConfigurator.kt:76)
        at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionApplicationBase.configureProject(InspectionApplicationBase.java:462)
        at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionApplicationBase.lambda$runUnderProgress$22(InspectionApplicationBase.java:698)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:189)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$12(CoreProgressManager.java:608)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:683)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:639)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:607)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:60)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
        at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionApplicationBase.runUnderProgress(InspectionApplicationBase.java:697)
        at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionApplicationBase.runAnalysis(InspectionApplicationBase.java:492)
        at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionApplicationBase.runAnalysisOnScope(InspectionApplicationBase.java:449)
        at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionApplicationBase.run(InspectionApplicationBase.java:221)
        at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionApplicationBase.execute(InspectionApplicationBase.java:159)
        at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionApplicationBase.startup(InspectionApplicationBase.java:123)
        at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionMain.main(InspectionMain.java:115)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.ApplicationStarter.main(ApplicationStarter.java:52)
        at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$initApplication$4.accept(ApplicationLoader.kt:176)
        at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$initApplication$4.accept(ApplicationLoader.kt)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniAccept.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:714)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1742)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1728)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Gradle project <unnamed>:0 resolve failed.
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.GradleCommandLineProjectConfigurator$StateNotificationListener.onFailure(GradleCommandLineProjectConfigurator.kt:179)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.ExternalSystemProgressNotificationManagerImpl$TaskListenerWrapper.onFailure(ExternalSystemProgressNotificationManagerImpl.kt:106)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher.dispatchVoidMethod(EventDispatcher.java:120)
        at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher.lambda$createMulticaster$1(EventDispatcher.java:85)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.onFailure(Unknown Source)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.ExternalSystemProgressNotificationManagerImpl$onFailure$1.invoke(ExternalSystemProgressNotificationManagerImpl.kt:65)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.ExternalSystemProgressNotificationManagerImpl$onFailure$1.invoke(ExternalSystemProgressNotificationManagerImpl.kt:17)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.ExternalSystemProgressNotificationManagerImpl.forEachListener(ExternalSystemProgressNotificationManagerImpl.kt:90)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.ExternalSystemProgressNotificationManagerImpl.onFailure(ExternalSystemProgressNotificationManagerImpl.kt:65)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:56)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:115)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:151)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:135)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.executeImpl(ExternalSystemUtil.java:491)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.lambda$execute$0(ExternalSystemUtil.java:327)
        at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceHeavyActivities.suspendIndexingAndRun(DumbServiceHeavyActivities.java:21)
        at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.suspendIndexingAndRun(DumbServiceImpl.java:190)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:327)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:614)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.startTask(CoreProgressManager.java:442)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.startTask(ProgressManagerImpl.java:114)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressInCurrentThread$10(CoreProgressManager.java:561)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:189)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$12(CoreProgressManager.java:608)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:683)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:639)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:607)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:60)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcessWithProgressInCurrentThread(CoreProgressManager.java:561)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.run(CoreProgressManager.java:381)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.Task.queue(Task.java:119)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil.refreshProject(ExternalSystemUtil.java:616)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil.refreshProject(ExternalSystemUtil.java:282)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.autoimport.ProjectAware.reloadProject(ProjectAware.kt:62)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.autoimport.AutoImportProjectTracker.reloadProject(AutoImportProjectTracker.kt:141)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.autoimport.AutoImportProjectTracker.access$reloadProject(AutoImportProjectTracker.kt:33)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.autoimport.AutoImportProjectTracker$scheduleProjectRefresh$1.invoke(AutoImportProjectTracker.kt:76)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.autoimport.AutoImportProjectTracker$scheduleProjectRefresh$1.invoke(AutoImportProjectTracker.kt:33)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.autoimport.AutoImportProjectTracker$schedule$1.invoke(AutoImportProjectTracker.kt:103)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.autoimport.AutoImportProjectTracker$schedule$1.invoke(AutoImportProjectTracker.kt:33)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.autoimport.update.PriorityEatUpdate$Companion$invoke$1.run(PriorityEatUpdate.kt:15)
        at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.queue(MergingUpdateQueue.java:347)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.autoimport.AutoImportProjectTracker.schedule(AutoImportProjectTracker.kt:98)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.autoimport.AutoImportProjectTracker.scheduleProjectRefresh(AutoImportProjectTracker.kt:76)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.GradleCommandLineProjectConfigurator.importProjects(GradleCommandLineProjectConfigurator.kt:95)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.GradleCommandLineProjectConfigurator.configureProject(GradleCommandLineProjectConfigurator.kt:75)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: The project directory does not exist!
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(GradleExecutionErrorHandler.java:197)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.java:46)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.doGetUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:167)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:48)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.checkErrorsWithoutQuickFixes(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:62)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$1.getUserFriendlyError(GradleProjectResolver.java:877)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:806)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:775)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.lambda$execute$0(GradleExecutionHelper.java:138)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.maybeFixSystemProperties(GradleExecutionHelper.java:165)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.lambda$execute$1(GradleExecutionHelper.java:138)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.GradleConnectorService$Companion.withGradleConnection(GradleConnectorService.kt:181)
        at ...
2022-11-11 09:17:15,378 [  18054] SEVERE - #c.i.c.InspectionApplicationBase - IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1  Build #IC-221.5591.52
2022-11-11 09:17:15,380 [  18056] SEVERE - #c.i.c.InspectionApplicationBase - JDK: 11.0.14.1; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2022-11-11 09:17:15,382 [  18058] SEVERE - #c.i.c.InspectionApplicationBase - OS: Linux
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Gradle project <unnamed>:0 resolve failed.
vkl@debian:~/*$ echo $?
1
vkl@debian:~/*$ ls inspection/
```

Comment: Try disabling **Android** plugin. Also try re-import project: delete existing `.idea` directory and open project using File | New | Project from Existing Sources... action.

Comment: There was indeed an Android plugin enabled in Idea, but disabling it doesn't change anything in the repo. Where is this change stored? In any case, disabling it gets rid of all the exceptions but the HeadlessException, and the `inspections` folder is still empty

Comment: Ah, my bad, I ran the command in the wrong directory *facepalm*. Disabling the Android plugin solved the problem, the inspection now works. If you post an answer I will accept it. I am still interested in learning disabling the plugin can be kept in the repo, so that it works the same way for everyone and for the CI

Comment: The Android plugin can be disabled by writing `org.jetbrains.android` to `${HOME}/.config/JetBrains/Idea${VERSION}/disabled_plugins.txt`